# Pandas Dataframe: convert Date format between two totally different formats

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with Date with the following formats:

Year-Month-Day

> ```
>  2000-02-01  
>  2000-02-02 
>  2000-02-03
> ```

I would like it to be like this:

Month/Day/Year

> ```
>  02/01/2000  
>  02/02/2000 
>  02/03/2000
> ```

Not only the parts of the date must be rearranged, but also the symbol "/" must separate the parts of the date.

How to do that with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are strings use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), but then datetimes are converted to strings:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
         date
0  02/01/2000
1  02/02/2000
2  02/03/2000
```

If values are datetimes only use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```